# VBA Wait till file is downloaded

Tags: vba

I am downloading an image from the web with VBA to my local machine and then moving that image to a server.  Additionally, I'm compressing that image to thumbnail size and moving that file to the server as well.

In both cases, I am getting the following error when I try to move the file to the server:

[image: Run-time error '75': Path/File access error]

I have tried using the following code to wait until the file exists to move it:

```vb
Do While Dir(sLocalFile & ".jpg") = ""
    DoEvents
Loop
```

But I still get the error message.

Additionally, if I click the "Debug" button and immediately click "Continue" of push F5, the macro finishes executing without a problem, indicating that even though `Dir` indicates that the file exists, it is not ready to be moved (i.e. probably still being written to).  Therefore, I tried to use the following code to to continue trying to move the file till it can do so without error:

```vb
MoveFile:
    On Error GoTo MoveFile
    Name sLocalFile & ".jpg" As ServPath & PartNum & ".jpg"
    On Error GoTo 0
```

However, I still got the same error (I also tried switching the label and the `On Error` command, but that didn't change anything).

**Edit:** Here is the function I'm using to download the file:

```vb
Function DownloadFile(sSourceURL As String, _
    sLocalFile As String _
) As Boolean
    DownloadFile = URLDownloadToFile(0&, _
                                     sSourceURL, _
                                     sLocalFile, _
                                     BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, _
                                     0& _
                                     ) = ERROR_SUCCESS
End Function
```

I found it somewhere online, and have only a rudimentary understanding of what it's doing.

**Edit 2:** I should add that this macro is running from inside SolidWorks and in cases where there isn't an image for the object available online, I'm generating the image with SolidWorks using the following code:

```vb
Dim sUrl As String, sLocalFile As String
sUrl = UserFormImportPart.TextBoxImgURL
sLocalFile = "C:\temp\" & UserFormImportPart.TextBoxPartNum
If sUrl = "" Then
    With swApp
        .SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e.swExportJpegCompression, 100
        .SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e.swTiffScreenOrPrintCapture, 1
        .SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e.swTiffPrintDPI, 400
    End With
    With swModel
        .ShowNamedView2 "*Isometric", 7
        .ViewZoomtofit2
        .Extension.InsertScene "\scenes\01 basic scenes\11 white kitchen.p2s"
        .SaveAs3 sLocalFile & ".jpg", 0, 0
        .Extension.InsertScene "\scenes\01 basic scenes\00 3 point faded.p2s"
        If Len(Dir(sLocalFile)) > 0 Then
            Kill sLocalFile
        End If
        Name sLocalFile & ".jpg" As sLocalFile
    End With
Else
    DownloadFile sUrl, sLocalFile
End If
```

The error occurs both when I'm downloading the file and when I'm generating it with SolidWorks.

Comment: Exactly how are you downloading the file?

Comment: See my edit at the end of my post.

Comment: I just remembered that I'm not always downloading the image. This is running from inside SolidWorks and if for some reason there isn't an image available online, I'm generating the image from the SolidWorks model. The same error occurs no matter what the source of the image. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Could you maybe check for the file's existence and if it's there note its size, then pause a few seconds and try again to see if the sizes match?  Any change would indicate if the file was still being written.

You could either use a WinAPI function ("Sleep"?) or maybe Excel's built-in Application.OnTime method to achieve the pause.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @NeepNeepNeep's comment, I was able to come up with this that seems to be working fairly well:

```vb
Do While Dir(sLocalFile & ".jpg") = ""
    DoEvents
Loop
Sleep 10
NewLen = 1
Do While NewLen > OldLen
    OldLen = NewLen
    NewLen = FileLen(sLocalFile & ".jpg")
    If NewLen < OldLen Then
        NewLen = OldLen + 1
    End If
Loop
OldLen = 0

Name sLocalFile & ".jpg" As ServPath & PartNum & ".jpg"
```